# Why does Django admin change form for User model use wrong datetime format?

Tags: python, django, datetime

Each time I try to edit a User object in the Django admin, I get the error

```
ValidationError at /admin/auth/user/1/
[u'Enter a valid date.']
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    ..admin/auth/user/1/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    [u'Enter a valid date.']
Exception Location:     path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py in to_python, line 406
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

I can see from the POST data (or by examing the hidden fields with Firebug) that the fields:

```
initial-last_login_0    u'14/10/2014'
initial-date_joined_0   u'14/10/2014'
```

are in the `%d/%m/%Y` format whereas the to be updated values get POSTed as `last_login_0 u'2014-10-14'`.  The datetime of the initial fields is not in a supported format as I can see by examing `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`.

Why is Django putting my datetimes in this format on the user change form? when it does not actually support them?

Some possibly relevant settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_GB'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Are you sure your settings.py file does not have some sort of weird DATETIME_FORMAT declared?

Comment: Not in settings.py or local_settings.py.

Comment: I found since that if I set `USE_L10N = False` then hidden datetime fields on the change form go back to things like `2014-10-14` and there is no validation error. Why would `USE_L10N` update the format in the form, but not update the accept DATE_INPUT_FORMAT?

Comment: From what I understand if you set that to True, Django tries to set datetime format based on your locale.  If you set it to false it then uses the format you define in your settings.py file.  I'm really not 100% familiar with the subject.